# Using WebSocket Secure with Nginx and Daphne

Tags: ssl, nginx, websocket, django-channels, daphne

I've been struggling to figure it all out, but I finally have something working with the following:

`nginx`:

```
server {
    server_name example.com;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/example/example;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/tmp/daphne.sock;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}

server {
    if ($host = www.example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

`daphne.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=daphne daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
User=example
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/example/example
StandardOutput=file:/var/example.log
StandardError=file:/var/example.log
ExecStart=/home/example/example/venv/bin/daphne \
          -u /tmp/daphne.sock \
          project.asgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I'm constrained to using `https`. The page does load with that. However, if I try and make a websocket connection it fails with something about mixed protocols. So I change 'ws://' to 'wss://' and now I get `The URL 'wss://' is invalid.` How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was quite simple to resolve. In my JavaScript I had

```js
new WebSocket(
        window.location.protocol == 'https:' ? 'wss://' : 'ws://'
        + window.location.host
        + '/ws/'
);
```

when I should have had

```js
new WebSocket(
        (window.location.protocol == 'https:' ? 'wss://' : 'ws://')
        + window.location.host
        + '/ws/'
);
```

Note the parentheses.